# WDS Warnings while compiling

Tags: webpack-dev-server, scala.js, scalajs-bundler

If I define a bare scalajs build.sbt as below with no actual scala code (App is an empty class):

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

lazy val repro = project.in(file(".")).settings(

    name := "Repro",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8",

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.6"
    ),

    mainClass in Compile := Some("App"),

    scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true,

    webpackDevServerPort := 3000
)
```

with the following two plugins:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.27")

addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.15.0")
```

Then whenever I rung fastOptJS::startWebpackDevServer I get a pile of warnings like below. Is there anything I can do to get rid of these warnings?

> [WDS] Warnings while compiling. client:147
>
> ./repro-fastopt.js (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>   Cannot find source file
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Boolean.scala':
>   Error: Can't resolve
>   './https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Boolean.scala'
>   in '/home/des/workspace/repro/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main' 
>   @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   ./repro-fastopt.js client:153
>
> ./repro-fastopt.js (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>   Cannot find source file
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Byte.scala':
>   Error: Can't resolve
>   './https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Byte.scala'
>   in '/home/des/workspace/repro/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main' 
>   @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   ./repro-fastopt.js client:153
>
> ./repro-fastopt.js (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>   Cannot find source file
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Character.scala':
>   Error: Can't resolve
>   './https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Character.scala'
>   in '/home/des/workspace/repro/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main' 
>   @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   ./repro-fastopt.js client:153
>
> ./repro-fastopt.js (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>   Cannot find source file
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Class.scala':
>   Error: Can't resolve
>   './https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Class.scala'
>   in '/home/des/workspace/repro/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main' 
>   @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   ./repro-fastopt.js client:153
>
> ./repro-fastopt.js (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
>   Cannot find source file
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Double.scala':
>   Error: Can't resolve
>   './https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scala-js/scala-js/v1.0.0-M7/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang/Double.scala'
>   in '/home/des/workspace/repro/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main'

...